# Get a trigger on page visit?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

It's so simple yet i can't figure it out.

I would like to write to DB on page visit (*without* Google Analytics).
I would like to do it on server side.

Since there is no trigger for it, and I redirect all requests to a function, i tried :

```
exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
...
...
    return response.redirect(url + "?action=" + action ) 
 
     .then(function(){   //  **** error : .then of undefined
        //write to DB a visit
```

Now this will return error since `response.redirect` will not return a promise. (as Frank said)

1. I could write to DB *before* I redirect user, then i make the website slower.
2. I could do so from client side, which have security problems.

How would I capture and save every page visit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a callable Cloud Function, sending a response to the client is a signal that the request is completely handled, and that Cloud Functions can shut down the contain/use it for other requests.

So there is no way to continue processing after you send the redirect back to the client. You'll either have to perform an additional request from the client, or wait with sending the redirect until you've sent the event to the database.

Note that you won't have to wait for a response from the database, which is how many analytics systems deal with this situation. They send the response, and then trust that the majority if events will make it through.

Comment: Oh wow, so sending the analytics first with a promise, and .then(function(){}.. will not wait for the respond from db ? I thought that the whole point with promise is that we wait for the returned value from the promise.

Comment: It depends on the backend system. What you're looking for is a system where you can send the request and forget about it. If tying back to promises, you'd want something that resolves the promise once the request is *sent*, not when the response is received.